# Lagrange multipliers: how could this be outside the restriction?

Tags: trigonometry, lagrange-multiplier

I have to get the extrema of function $f(x,y)=\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(y)$ restricted to $x+y=\frac{\pi}{2}$. So this is what I did:

$$g(x,y)=x+y=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\nabla f(x,y)=\lambda.\nabla g(x,y)$$

So I got the gradients of both functions:

$$\nabla f(x,y)=<-2\cos(x)\sin(x); -2\cos(y)\sin(y)>$$

$$\nabla g(x,y)=<1;1>$$

From where I got the equation system where:
$$
\begin{cases}
-2\cos(x)\sin(x)=1 \\
-2\cos(y)\sin(y)=1 \\
x+y=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

I solved the first one as:

$$\sin(2x)=-1 \\
x=\frac{arcsin(-1)}{2} \\
x=-\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
So, since the second equation is the same for $y$, then also $y=-\frac{\pi}{4}$

From all this, I get the extrema must be at $(-\frac{\pi}{4}; -\frac{\pi}{4})$. However, this contradicts my restriction of $x+y=\frac{\pi}{2}$ because of $x$ and $y$ signs.

So, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Note that it is $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g.$ That is, $-2\cos x\sin x=\lambda$ instead of $-2\cos x\sin x=1.$

Comment: Well, thank you for pointint out my obvious mistake :D  Now I got to the point where $x=\frac{\arcsin(-\lambda)}{2}$ thus $y$ is the same (from the first 2 equations). With that in mind, I plug in those in the constraint and get $\frac{\arcsin(-\lambda)}{2} + \frac{\arcsin(-\lambda)}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$. And from that I get that $\lambda=1$. So I plug that value of $\lambda$ in the first 2 equations again and finally get that both $x$ and $y$ are $-\frac{\pi}{2}$. Which takes me to the same question... this doesn't seem to fit in the constraint where $x+y=\frac{\pi}{2}$... what's wrong?

Comment: Note that $\sin x=\sin y$ doesn't imply $x=y.$ I have given a hint in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

From $\nabla f=\lambda  \nabla g$ we get

\begin{cases}\sin 2x=-\lambda\\ \sin 2y=-\lambda\end{cases} Since $\sin t$ is $2\pi$-periodic we have that $\sin 2t$ is $\pi$-periodic. Thus we get that $2y=2x+k\pi,$ for some integer $k.$ That is, $y=x+\frac {k\pi}2.$ Using the constraint $x+y=\frac \pi2$ we get that $2x+\frac {k\pi}2=\frac \pi2.$ That is, $x=\frac{(1-k)\pi}{4}.$ Thus $y=\frac {(k+1)\pi}4.$

Comment: are you sure about the solution?

Answer (score 0):

i have $$-2\sin(x)\cos(x)=-\lambda$$ and so on, you have forgotten a minus sign.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to see where that minus sign in $\lambda$ comes from (after noticing I missed the whole lambda, which is the point of the Lagrange multipliers!).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see that the function is constant restricted to $x+y={\pi\over2}\Longrightarrow y={\pi\over2}-x$:

$$f(x,y={\pi\over2}-x)=f(x)=\cos^2x+\cos^2\left({\pi\over2}-x\right)=\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$$

because $\cos\left({\pi\over2}-x\right)=\sin x$.